# Why components added from Android Studio's designer, looks different then the ones added on runtime?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am curious why is this happening. I have added 2 checkboxes in designer

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

And added some on runtime

```
for (String category : userData.getFilters().getCategories().keySet()) {
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox(getContext()); // getActivity() gives same result, after all activit == context here
            box.setTag(category);
            box.setText(category);
            categoriesContainer.addView(box);
        }
```

They looks like this:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you are not creating **AppCompatCheckBox** but `CheckBox`

`AppCompatCheckBox` should work -

```
AppCompatCheckBox checkBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(context);
```

**Side Note :**

Before `Android support v22.1 library`, if you create components dynamically, they don't pick the material design theme.

But from `v22.1 support library` and above, this works. You should use `CheckBox` from `support library` and it will use a material theme which is used for components created via `XML`.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Please tell me, should I try to avoid using any sort of support libraries, or rather I should stick to them?

Comment: @Antoniossss I prefer to use support libraries as this way you can get backward compatibility. However, in case you are targetting only latest API level, you won't need backward compatibilty. So no support libraray in that case. If you are using support library, you can use specific support library you need instead of importing all support libraries. Example - compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1' in your case.

Comment: Ok, so my feeling was right about trying to avoid support libaries(as I am targeting API 19). Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are targeting API level 19 and you want to use some feature from API level 23, then to reflect that exact feature on API level 19, you have to use support library because API19 don't have that feature. Just to be clear :-)

Comment: Yes, I totally understand that, but I doubt that I will be using features missing in API 19. If ill get to such point, Ill include proper support lib. Thanks.